# Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy intentando consultar los datos que tiene una columna, pero actualmente tengo este error. Intenté resolverlo pero no pude. ¿Alguna mano?

```php
$resultado1 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM skins WHERE Nick = 'Federico'");
mysqli_data_seek ($resultado1, 0);
$resultado1 = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado1);
echo $resultado1['Value']; //Línea de error (Trying to access array offset on value of type null)
```

Esta es mi tabla
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la muestra de la estructura de la tabla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que es value? y porque esta entre comillas simples?

Comment: Value vendría siendo una columna

Comment: El campo Value no existe en tu tabla, intenta con otro campo , tu consulta funciona bien.

Comment: @rpaillao Mira la publicación, añadí una imagen de lo que vendría siendo mi tabla.

Comment: usa player_name , con eso debería bastar.

Comment: perdón, me equivoque de tabla, mis disculpas, actualicé denuevo la publicación @rpaillao

Comment: has un ``var_dump($resultado1);`` para asegurarse que hay algun resultado.

Comment: Me otorga un valor NULL

Comment: Y hay alguien con ese nick?

Comment: Es una de dos cosas. 1- no estás conectando correctamente a la base de datos (revisa los datos de: usuario, contraseña y BD en la línea de conexión). 2- No existe un registro que cumpla con `WHERE Nick='Federico'`. En ese caso, debes colocar un `if($resultado1) { /* imprimir o procesar los datos */} else { echo "Ese Nick no aparece registrado"; }`

Comment: @gbianchi fué un ejemplo, probé con la cuenta que hay y tampoco funciona

Comment: @aeportugal verifiqué si yo estaba bien conectado a la base de datos y estoy en lo correcto, server:local, usuario:root, database: rivexmc, contraseña no es necesario.

Comment: y la tabla es de skins

Comment: Creo que podría ser el largo del elemento del array, estuve buscando información, pero no logré encontrar los limites de los elementos, por lo que veo en tu imagen tu dato es tipo TEXT y ese tipo de campos puede almacenar archivos de gran tamaño, por lo que veo que por ahí estaría el detalle, no creo que un array tenga la misma característica.

Comment: ¿Por qué usas `mysqli_data_seek` en este código? Por otra parte, estás programando de un modo demasiado optimista o ingenuo y eso crea un código débil en el cual no se preven eventuales problemas para afrontarlos.

Comment: @A.Cedano Estoy intentando utilizar eso para transformarlo en array con mysqli_fetch_array, una manera de ajustarlo, de otra manera, este código lo utilizo para que los jugadores puedan ver sus propias estadísticas en tu página web, desde de un servidor de juego.

Comment: @rpaillao Intenté con el mismo código en otra tabla, y funciona correctamente, desgraciadamente la tabla se genera automáticamente con esos valores por un plugin, desde un servidor de juego, pero podría resolverlo manualmente, ¿alguna ídea que podría hacer?

Comment: No creo que sea necesario usar`mysqli_data_seek` para eso. Si esperas varios resultados, aplica `fetch` dentro de un `while`, si esperas una sola fila, aplica `fetch` directamente y si quieres una fila aleatoria es mejor hacerlo desde la misma instruccción SQL que usas para consultar a la tabla.

Comment: @A.Cedano Bien, ya lo hice, pero todavía estoy obteniendo el mismo error, probé el código con otra tabla y si funciona bien, pero veo que en esta no, ¿que error tendría?

Comment: ¿Si ejecutas esto directamente en la base de datos: `SELECT * FROM skins WHERE Nick = 'Federico';` muestra algo?

Comment: @A.Cedano Si, me muestra todos los datos de ese usuario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu código implementa lo que yo llamo *programación optimista o ingenua*. Consiste en programar pensando que todo irá bien (optimismo).

Lamentablemente no todo va bien siempre, por más que uno quiera, de modo que una de tus principales tareas como programador es prever todo aquello que podría salir mal y controlarlo (programación pesimista).

Vamos a aplicarlo en tu programa:

```
#Verificamos que haya conexión
if ($link) {
    $sql="SELECT * FROM skins WHERE Nick = 'Federico'";
    #Verificamos que query fue exitosa
    if ( $rs = mysqli_query($link, $sql) ) {
        $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs);
    } else {
        $data ['error'] = sprintf( 'Error en la consulta SQL: %s', mysqli_error($link) );
    }
} else {
    $data ['error'] = 'No hay conexión';
}
#Para prueba
var_dump($data);
```

En el código hemos creado un array `$data` que tendrá una clave `error` cuando alguno ocurra, y un mensaje asociado que describe el error ocurrido.

Hicimos solamente una prueba de `$data` con `var_dump`, cuando verifiques lo que hay en la variable podrás escribir código para usar esos datos o mandarlos a otro sitio.